# Removing dropdown arrow on combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I remove the arrow from a combobox in windows forms? I've looked through the "Properties"-panel and found no solution there, is this possible at all?

Comment: I don't know if you can, you might have to create a custom control if you can't find it.

Comment: I think you need to change the style of the combobox. It can't be done easily, with a parameter :(

Comment: this is the look and feel of combobox in winform. How do you tell the user it is a _clickable, downward expandable_ list, not an edit control?

Comment: I only want to make the combobox searchable with multiple objects, I don't want the whole list to show up?

Comment: The real question is: why are you looking for a way to remove the button? What is a combobox without the button?

Comment: I want to create a search field with autocomplete for two different objects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you mentioned that your actual goal is to have auto-complete.

For auto-complete, you don't use a ComboBox; you use a TextBox and set some extra properties. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629909/87399) for an answer on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a text box then with autocomplete functionality, several links here:
[How to make an auto-complete textbox in a winforms desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629909/how-to-make-an-auto-complete-textbox-in-a-winforms-desktop-application)