# Why aren't any items showing in my TextBox's autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a TextBox in my Windows Forms project which as part of a table holds a description of some material a company will buy. To ensure that the company enforces consistent naming, I have implemented autocomplete on the TextBox as so:

```
 AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(pastItems);
desc.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
desc.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
desc.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

But when I am typing anything into the TextBox, the dropdown is not populating.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint at the line `source.AddRange(pastItems);`, is `pastItems` a List containing actual data ?

Comment: Your code looks very similar to what is shown in [this other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216863/3775798) and they indicated in the comments there that it works, so definitely check what @MartinVerjans suggested above. Also, have you considered using a ComboBox control instead?

Comment: based on requirement i need to use only text box

Comment: and with textbox i need to show one dropdown which contain all the item filtered based on enterd text in textbox.